Docker-in-docker/Gitlab-CI Cannot use docker command running on Kubernetes Cluster
From subject my gitlab-ci cannot use docker command. With ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
This is my gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:latest  # this sets default image for jobs
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# Define variables that can be used throughout the pipeline
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: "my_image"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

# Use Docker-in-Docker service to enable Docker commands
services:
  - docker:dind

# Build stage
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - echo "Ensuring Docker daemon is running..."
    - docker info
  script:
    - echo "Building the Docker image..."
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .

# Deployment stage
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - echo "Ensuring Docker daemon is running..."
    - docker info
  script:
    - echo "Deploying..."
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
  only:
    - master  # Only deploy from the master branch

and this is my runner helm values.yaml
gitlabUrl: "https://gitlab.thaibevapp.com"
runnerRegistrationToken: "*"
runners:
  image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:ubuntu-v16.11.1
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        privileged = true
        image = "ubuntu:22.04"
        timeout = 3600
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        dns_policy = "none"
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "docker"
          mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        [runners.kubernetes.dns_config]
          nameservers = [
            "10.233.0.3",
          ]
          searches = [
            "default.svc.cluster.local",
            "svc.cluster.local",
            "cluster.local",
          ]
      [[runners.kubernetes.dns_config.options]]
        name = "ndots"
        value = "2"
        
hostAliases: 
   - ip: "10.111.0.143"
     hostnames:
     - "gitlab.thaibevapp.com"
     - "registry.thaibevapp.com"
     - "minio.thaibevapp.com"
     - "kas.thaibevapp.com"
     
rbac:
  create: true

